# Stop header code from showing in category page?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, archives, headers

Hi I'm using the code below to show different header images in my custom template archives.

Only problem is that it is also showing the headers in the category templates.

go to http://tv-cafe.com/category/video that image at the top isn't suppose to be there, how do i get that to not show.

```
<?php
if ( ! is_home() ) {

if ( get_post_type() == 'pretty-little-liars' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/pllbanner.png"></div>';
}
if ( get_post_type() == 'revenge' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/revenge.png"></div>';
}
if ( get_post_type() == 'grimm' ) {
    echo '<div id="headerimg"><img src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/girmmbanner.png"></div>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you can also use this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by changing the conditional to

```
if ( !is_home() && !is_archive() )
```

Also consider using `if` and `else if`. So your optimized code would be:

```
<?php

    if ( !is_home() && !is_archive() ) {

        if ( get_post_type() == 'pretty-little-liars' ) {
            echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/pllbanner.png"></div>';
        } else if ( get_post_type() == 'revenge' ) {
            echo '<div id="headerimg"><img  src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/revenge.png"></div>';
        } else if ( get_post_type() == 'grimm' ) {
            echo '<div id="headerimg"><img src="http://tv-cafe.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/girmmbanner.png"></div>';
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, and instead of placing `is_archive`, i placed `is_category()` because my post types have archives that will be using those :)

Comment: Ok, did not know that :)